# How to remove hieroglyphs when connecting PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

Connecting a PostgreSQL database to PyCharm writes with hieroglyphs. What to do?
This is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` uses the language from the locale in its environment. Change that to English, and you will have less trouble reading the messages. On a Linux system, you could set the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable to `C`.

Comment: I opened the file on the way "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data\postgresql.conf" In the file it was necessary to change the variable lc_messages = "en_EN.UTF-8"
It helped me, thank you!